# How to print out the line number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I am working on a code for the tutorial. The code reads in a file `input.txt`, and checks each line to see whether the letters in the line can be used to make the word "aardvark" (Uppercase letters can be used as well).

Here is my code:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as text:

  for w in text:
    a = w.count('a')
    r = w.count('r')
    d = w.count('d')
    v = w.count('v')
    k = w.count('k')

    if a >= 3 and r >= 2 and d >= 1 and v >= 1 and k >= 1:
      print("Aardvark on line", w)
```

Here is my file:

```
No aardv*rks here!
Only armadillos and anteaters.
Animals are run down: very awful road kill.
I prefer a quick guacamole made from avocados.
```

The code printed out:

```
Aardvark on line Animals are run down: very awful road kill.
Aardvark on line I prefer a quick guacamole made from avocados.
```

The code worked fine, but I want to print out the line number instead of the line it self. Here is how I want to print out:

```
Aardvark on line 3
Aardvark on line 4
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Use enumerate to get numbers during iteration. `for i, w in enumerate(text):` and then `print("Aardvark on line", i)`

Comment: it prints out  `<enumerate object at 0xf6fa8324>`

Comment: What prints out `<enumerate object at 0xf6fa8324>` ? Check the comment i wrote. You need to use enumerate during the for loop, and use `i` to access the index

Comment: Ok it works now. I just needed to add 1 to `i` for my code.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use the built-in function enumerate()

```
 for idx, val in enumerate(ints):
        print(idx, val)
```

another solution in 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-accessing-index-and-value-in-list/

Comment: if you find a dupe answer, please link and flag the question as a dupe, don't copy paste the answer over.

Comment: sometimes you need to resume a lot of reading by just what you need to make it more simple

Comment: No, that actively hinders site curation. Please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) . Answering dupes may seem "nice" in the short run, but is very harmful for the site as a whole in the long run. Please do not answer dupes.

Comment: ok thanks i will consider this next time